# Post JSON to ASP.NET from iOS

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, json, post

I am trying to POST JSON data to my asp.net MVC server from an iPhone app. The method in my server looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public String MyMethod(Stream anUpload) { ... }
```

And here is the code to POST the JSON from my app:

```
NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.103/MyServer/MyMethod"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Serialize my data.
NSData *theData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:theList options:kNilOptions error:nil];

[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [theData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:theData];
```

However, when I send the request, I just get an error message from the server, the MyMethod() never gets called. I am assuming that there is an issue with ASP accepting the POST data. Any ideas?

EDIT: Answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

I just needed to change the server-side function to

`public String MyMethod(List<string> aList) { ... }`

The ModelBinder was trying to deserialize the JSON for me, and it didn't like my parameter being a Stream.